# HIVE ORC returns NULLs

Tags: hive, null, emr, orc

I am creating hive external table ORC (ORC file located on S3).

**Command**

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE Table1 (Id INT, Name STRING) STORED AS ORC LOCATION 's3://bucket_name'
```

**After running the query**:

```
Select * from Table1;
```

**Result is**:

```
+-------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+
| Table1.id  | Table1.name  |
+-------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+
| NULL                                | NULL                                  |
| NULL                                | NULL                                  |
| NULL                                | NULL                                  |
| NULL                                | NULL                                  |
| NULL                                | NULL                                  |
| NULL                                | NULL                                  |
| NULL                                | NULL                                  |
| NULL                                | NULL                                  |
| NULL                                | NULL                                  |
| NULL                                | NULL                                  |
+-------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+
```

Interesting that the number of returned records 10 and it is correct but all records are NULL. 
What is wrong, why query returns only NULLs? 
I am using EMR instances on AWS. Should I configure/check to support ORC format for hive?

Comment: are your files in ORC format? Please post a sample of your input file.

Comment: Yes, I am using ORC file. I tried to create an external table from s3 and from hdfs , but I got the same result. Here is an attachment with the file [link] https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3MYgurAigDMdm1ESkZYWm9Zdms/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

I did use your sample ORC file and tried to CREATE an external table in HIVE, I was able to see the data output.

[image: Hive Output]

You can also make use of the ORC Dump utility to get to know the metadata of the ORC file in JSon format.

```
hive --orcfiledump -j -p <Location of Orc File>
```

Try to load the data using the `LOAD` statement or creating a `Managed Table`, JFYI "I tried them all and was getting the data as below" :) I really dont find anything wrong with your statements.

You can also check the link for more information [ORC Dump](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+ORC#LanguageManualORC-ORCFileDumpUtility)

Answer (score 1):

I run into the same issue with EMR Hive and orc files located in s3. 
Problem was in mismatch between field name in orc schema and hive fields name.

In my case names should match 100% (including case sensitive) + note that hive will translate camelCase field names in lowercase.

In you case you it would be better to create table like:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE Table1 (id INT, name STRING) STORED AS ORC LOCATION 's3://bucket_name'
```

And when creating .orc files use schema like:

```
private final TypeDescription SCHEMA = TypeDescription.createStruct()
            .addField("id", TypeDescription.createInt())
            .addField("name", TypeDescription.createString());
```

In this case Hive field names match to field names in orc schema and EMR Hive was able to read values from those files.

Answer (score 0):

The issue I had was with the case of the column name in Hive table, if your ORC file have column name in upper case then the hive table should have the same case. I used spark data frame to convert the column to the lower case:

```
import findspark
findspark.init()
import pyspark
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark import SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pandas
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

orc_df=sqlContext.read.orc("hdfs://data/part-00000.snappy.orc")

new_orc_df=orc_df.select([F.col(x).alias(x.lower()) for x in orc_df.columns])
new_orc_df.printSchema()

new_orc_df.write.orc(os.path.join(tempfile.mkdtemp(), '/home/hadoop/vishrant/data'), 'overwrite')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try configuring orc.schema.evolution.case.sensitive to false.
[jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ORC-502)