# Hive table shows NULL values

Tags: hadoop, amazon-ec2, hive, amazon-emr

As per customer requirement, we are migrating the Hive database from AWS EC2 instance to AWS  EMR instance.
I have gathered all the create table statements as below

```
CREATE TABLE abc( col1 double, col2 double, col3 string, col4 timestamp, col5 string) 
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcSerde' STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcOutputFormat' LOCATION 's3a://oldprodbucket/hive_folder/hive_database.db/hive_database_ABC' 
TBLPROPERTIES ( 'COLUMN_STATS_ACCURATE'='false', 'numFiles'='0', 'numRows'='-1', 'orc.compress'='ZLIB', 'rawDataSize'='-1', 'totalSize'='0', 'transient_lastDdlTime'='1559130496')
```

We changed the Location value, where the data is present in the new bucket, as below.

```
CREATE TABLE abc( col1 double, col2 double, col3 string, col4 timestamp, col5 string) 
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcSerde' STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcOutputFormat' LOCATION 's3://prodbucket/hive_folder/hive_database.db/hive_database_ABC' 
TBLPROPERTIES ( 'COLUMN_STATS_ACCURATE'='false', 'numFiles'='0', 'numRows'='-1', 'orc.compress'='ZLIB', 'rawDataSize'='-1', 'totalSize'='0', 'transient_lastDdlTime'='1559130496')
```

But when triggering the SELECT query on the table, it shows all the columns as NULL.

```
| NULL                 | NULL                      | NULL                   | NULL                       | NULL
```

Can someone please help in this regards?

Comment: Have you tried running msck repair command? Did you compare raw files in the bucket? What tool did you use to move the files?

Comment: We are using S3 browser to copy the files from bucket to local machine and then from local machine to new bucket.

Comment: Okay, and msck repair?

Answer (score 0):

Stackoverflow link [HIVE ORC returns NULLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46914852/hive-orc-returns-nulls)
helped me to identify the issue.

With the help of Hive database Admin, we found the property named orc.force.positional.evolution.

After setting it to true as below, we are able to see the data correctly.

```
ALTER table TableName SET TBLPROPERTIES('orc.force.positional.evolution'='true');
```